# how can I get /usr/lib32 on my 32-bit ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, 10.04, libraries, shared-library

how can I get /usr/lib32 on my 32-bit ubuntu ? This file is missing on my system.

Comment: I think this is for 32bit programs on 64bit machines. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

32bit systems don't use `/usr/lib32/`, they use `/usr/lib/`. However, in the case of the nvidia drivers, they stick a pair of directories in there but nothing else.

```
$ tree -a /usr/lib32/
/usr/lib32/
├── nvidia-325
└── vdpau

2 directories, 0 files
```

Again, these directories are empty.